# Can you suggest some books for windows administration?

Tags: untagged

Please suggest some good books for the person who is going to setup windows server 2008 & sql server 2008 for shared hosting service.

Comment: What's your current experience level and familiarity level with Win Server and SQL? Background?...

Comment: SQL is OK from point of programmer. Queries, views, triggers etc - no problem

Comment: @Overdose: So basically starting from scratch with system administration of servers?

Comment: @Bart Silverstrim - i guess yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Windows Server 2008 Unleashed" by SAMS Publishing and "Introducing Microsoft SQL Server 2008" by Microsoft Press are good books.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever somebody asks for a book recommendation, I always feel compelled to mention O'Reilly's [Safari Books Online](http://www.safaribooksonline.com/Corporate/Index/).  It's an amazing resource of online books from many publishers.  I think I pay about $40 per month and I get full access to thousands of titles. (actually my work pays for it)

A quick search on SQL Server 2008 brings back 385 Results including "SQL Server 2008, Administration in Action" and "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Management and Administration."  Searching for Windows Server 2008 brings back 643 results including "Windows Server 2008 Unleashed" and "Introducing Windows Server 2008".

Sorry this isn't a specific book recommendation, but I use Safari as a "giant book."  If you can handle reading online, I recommend it highly over buying a bunch of paper.  I especially find it helpful to read about topics in multiple books; some are better in areas than others.

Answer (score 0):

After you are comfortable with the technology side of Windows and SQL Server then you should be ready for the looking at Systems Administration as a profession - [The Practice of System and Network Administration](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321492668).